# What are the adab a women should take on when working?

Tags: adab, modesty

I work in an INGO and I am the only female in my Office.  I do wear the Hijab,  but I wonder, what types of adab should I take on during the working hours?  What does Islam recommend for a women in the workplace?

Comment: Salam Alaikum, I have edited your question to be more clear Insha'Allah, I hope I did not change anything, if I did you are always free to change it by clicking on the edit button.  We welcome you to Islam.SE, and we want to ask if you may read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq), for in it is what you need to know about how things work here.  Also, we ask you take time and look at existing questions and answers.If you have a question use the search feature to find an answer if you find non, then you are free to ask.  We are looking forward to having you as an active participant here

Answer (score 5):

**1.Wearing Clothes that Covering the Aurat**. cover the aurat is an absolute requirement that must be met before a woman out of the house or working at the office. Because Allah Almighty has said unequivocally in the Quran:

[image]

"O Prophet, tell your wives and your daughters and the women of the believers to bring down over themselves [part] of their outer garments. That is more suitable that they will be known and not be abused. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful.". Surah Al-'Aĥzāb 33:59 (The Combined Forces)

**2.Not tabarruj or Showing off Jewelry and Beauty**. The woman who leaves the house or working at the office should be cover the aurat. She was forbidden showing off jewelry and beauty, especially in the presence of men. Because Allah Almighty has said in the Quran:

[image]

"And abide in your houses and do not display yourselves as [was] the display of the former times of ignorance. And establish prayer and give zakah and obey Allah and His Messenger. Allah intends only to remove from you the impurity [of sin], O people of the [Prophet's] household, and to purify you with [extensive] purification." Surat Al-'Aĥzāb 33:33 (The Combined Forces)

**3.Not softens the body and breathed the voice**. The women who leave the house or working at the office also forbidden to act that will make men orgasm. Such a sound that impressed tempt, or even his voice sighed.

[image]

"O wives of the Prophet, you are not like anyone among women. If you fear Allah , then do not be soft in speech [to men], lest he in whose heart is disease should covet, but speak with appropriate speech" Surat Al-'Aĥzāb 33:32 (The Combined Forces)

**4. keeping the Sight**. The woman who leave the house or working at the office are also required to keep his views. Not only men are forbidden darting her eyes, but women is also haram.

[image]

[image]

"Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is Acquainted with what they do (30). And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment except to their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might succeed (31)". Surat Al-'Aĥzāb 30-31 (The Combined Forces)

**5.Getting Permission From her parents or her husband**. It is most often forgotten, especially Muslim women activists because once they enter in routine activities, then as if the permission of the parents or husbands become forgotten. In fact permission is needed to be obtained and can not be underestimated. Basically the women must obtain her husband's approval to leave the house. Not a burden and a hindrance or coercion. Permission of the husband should be understood as a form of affection and attention as well as the manifestation of a responsibility that should ideally be a protector.

Answer (score -3):

I'm from Turkey.

To be honest, in Arabian countries and in Iran Islam has turned into something else. It is not Islam anymore. What they believe in is sickened and modified. As a result human rights is on the floor and Arabia has went back to middle age.

In Islam, there is NOTHING about dressing. Islam doesn't tell you how to dress. Islam is a religion of freedom and understanding. Islam is not a religion of captivity and forbids. Islam came to this world to show you the right way, not to tell you something silly like the way you dress. Do not believe in that. Believe in what you read, if you can find a good source. Most of the translations are wrongfully interpreted to benefit some cunning men and so it's hard to find a good source about real Islam.

God is so big. God doesn't think about your earthly matters like what hat you put on your head.

I know that this comment is gonna get a lot of negatives because many of the people have been brainwashed and their minds are closed from childhood. But we must speak of the truth.

Answer (score -4):

Quran refer to hide your private parts only.

Most verses regarding modesty refer to prophet's wives only. There is no dress code like blake abaya or something defined in quran. When quran refer women to be modest and forbid them to not look like the women in ***"times of ignorance"*** it refer to the old arab culture and roman culture.

Prophet's first wife khatija was a working women and prophet did work under her supervision. So I would suggest you to be yourself and do not impose a specific dress code on yourself and just stick to some small limitations quran told you to do.